# Given a wsdl service can more information about the server be obtained?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, xml-rpc

Lets say we have a wsdl file and  as

```
<wsdl:service name="abc">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:abc" name="abcport">
      <soap:address location="https://example.com/dlps"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
```

Can we get more specific information of the server on which this webservice is hosted. For now I am more interested in I.P. address of the server.

I am just thinking if the UDDI can be queried in some way.

Comment: Do you want to have server's DNS lookup?

Comment: Anything can help

Comment: Not sure if the webservice is registered on UDDI. If registered on which UDDI.

Comment: Well I am not sure that if I understood the question correctly. But you can lookup something [here](https://mxtoolbox.com/DNSLookup.aspx). Probably that'd help.

Comment: Also, this answer on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12405654/check-the-dns-lookup-of-a-nameserver-in-java#answer-12405896

Comment: Try from the command line nslookup example.com in windows or host -t a example.com in unix wouldn't they give you the required information

Comment: I am getting invalid type error

Answer (score 0):

Getting an IP from a domain name.

```
nslookup example.com
```

Or you could tracert it:

```
tracert -d example.com
```

Does this get me more information or allow me to query UDDI?

Depends if the server implemented UDDI.